# Group By and Pivot using SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Having an issue with trying to pivot a dataset (not sure if this is transposing or not?)

Let's say I have Table 1:

```
Name       Food       Price  
 ------ -------------- ------- 
  Matt   Cheeseburger       5  
  Bill   Hotdog             4  
  Bill   Steak             10  
  Andy   Hotdog             4  
  Andy   Cheeseburger       5  
  Andy   Nachos             5
```

How would I be able to group by the name, but then transpose the other columns to get something like Table 2?

Table 2:

```
Name      Food_1         Food_2      Food_3   Price_1   Price_2   Price_3  
 ------ -------------- -------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- 
  Matt   Cheeseburger                                 5                      
  Bill   Hotdog         Steak                         4        10            
  Andy   Hotdog         Cheeseburger   Nachos         4         5         5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange in `ms-access` but you can tackle using `subquery` :

```
select t.name, 
       max(iff(rnk = 1, Food)) as food_1,
       max(iff(rnk = 2, Food)) as food_2,
       max(iff(rnk = 3, Food)) as food_3,
       max(iff(rnk = 1, Price)) as price_1,        
       max(iff(rnk = 2, Price)) as price_2,        
       max(iff(rnk = 3, Price)) as price_3        
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table as t1
              where t1.name = t.name and t1.id <= t.id 
             ) as rnk
      from table as t
     ) as t
group by t.name;
```

This assumes your table has `identity` column so, i just used as `id`.

Comment: Currently getting an issue where values less than the max rnk are being cut off. For example, Price_1 has no value if there's a Price_2 or Price_1 and Price_2 have no value if there is a Price_3. I'm also a newbie to SO, how do you embed ASCII tables into here so I can show this better?

Comment: Actually, the identity column was throwing that off and everything works as should. Thanks!